# ERROR: (0 , _cucumber.And) is not a function

Tags: automation, cucumber, keyword, gherkin, feature-file

I have tried to use 'And' keyword in `Cucumber` and I get this error. Could someone tell me the reason behind this?

In step definition:

```
import { When,Then,And } from 'cucumber';

Given(/^User goes to login page$/, () => {
  loginPage.goToLogin();
});

And(/^Enters wrong credentials$/, () => {
  loginPage.enterData();
});
```

In feature file, it is used as:

```
Given User goes to login page
And Enters wrong credentials
```

When I run the test case, I got this error:

```
ERROR: (0 , _cucumber.And) is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use `And` in step definitions. You can use `Given`, `Then` or even `When` in step definition. The keywords `And` and `But` are mainly used in feature file to make it read more fluently by writing.

For example--

.. #.feature

```
  Scenario:Check Google home page title
  Given I go to the website
  And I go to the website again
  Then I expect the title of the page "Google"
```

..
    #.StepDefinition.js

```
import { Given, Then, When } from "cucumber";

let chai = require('chai');
global.expect = chai.expect;



  Given(/^I go to the google site$/, () => {
    browser.url("http://www.google.com");
  });

  When(/^I go to the google site again$/, () => {
    browser.url("http://www.google.com");
  });

  Then(/^I expect the title of the page "([^"]*)"$/, (title) => {
    expect(browser.getTitle()).to.be.eql(title);
  });
```

This will work.

Comment: I would like to use AND in step definition. How do I do it.